# KOMA-Script/Twoside > Extra right margin on odd and even page :-S

Tags: margins, koma-script, double-sided

I'm trying to use *KOMA-Script* with `scrbook` class but whatever I do, I always have an extra margin on the right of every page. Does anyone have an idea to strip of this space ?

Here are some illustrations of my problem (in orange the extra space) :

[image: 1st page]
[image: 2nd page]

The strip only appears with XeLatex (with PdfLatex there is no problem at all)

Here is a kind of minimal example :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside=true,BCOR=0pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{showframe}

\author{John Doe}
\title{My super Title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{My first chapter}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Sorry, but I can't understand where is the extra space. Can you explain it better?

Comment: See `BCOR`. You can do: `BCOR=0pt`

Comment: Yes, I'll try to ! In each figure the orange part was initially white but I colored it with an image editor. I was thinking that this white strip have nothing to do there ? Moreover it is always on the right side of each page whatever it is an odd or even page.

Comment: BCOR=0pt is working fine in this minimal exemple. I'll provide a new minimal exemple where BCOR=0pt is not solving my problem :-$

Comment: Okay, with BCOR=0pt, everything is working when I compile with pdfLatex but I was using XeLatex and I can't figure why this is not working with it (even with BCOR=0pt). Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: How do you see that? In my case with no tools, just by compiling again and seeing how the new pdf looks compared to the old one… I get the exact output with and without `BCOR0pt`, and with pdflatex and xelatex. Which could mean that (1) I don't have the tools to see that difference, (2) you have a different instalation than mine, or (3) your minimal example is not a minimal working example for your problem.

Comment: I'm using the MacTex distribution with TeXworks editor and I can confirm that this minimal exemple works with PdfLatex on my machine only with BCOR=0pt but not with XeLatex (even with BCOR=0pt).

Comment: The orange strip appears to be outside the page area in the image you posted. That is, it is to the right of the black line which seems to mark the edge of the page. Am I missing something?

Comment: It appears to me as being outside the layout but inside the page (when I open it with preview or Acrobat or ... the strip is still visible)